# How to create 2 x 2 grid using NativeScript GridLayout

Tags: css, nativescript

### The Problem

I am trying to simply display images in 2 rows, 2 columns - equally centered all around.

I have tried all sorts of Layouts. Here are a couple of my failures:

[image: Fail 1]

[image]

### My Ideal Layout

[image: Solution]

**My XML**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page"
    xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar customActionBar" >
        <!-- 
        Use the NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in Android
        because ActionItems are shown on the right side of the ActionBar
        -->
        <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" tap="onDrawerButtonTap"></NavigationButton>
        <!-- 
        Use the ActionItem for IOS with position set to left. Using the
        NavigationButton as a side-drawer button in iOS is not possible,
        because its function is to always navigate back in the application.
        -->
        <ActionItem icon="res://navigation/menu" 
            android:visibility="collapsed" 
            tap="onDrawerButtonTap"
            ios.position="left"></ActionItem>
        <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Signup"></Label>
    </ActionBar>
    <DockLayout width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="lightgray" class="page-gradient"
        stretchLastChild="false">
        <Button class="submitButton h2 border" text="Next" height="60" dock="bottom"
            tap="onSignupButtonTap" returnKeyType="next"/>
        <!-- content -->
        <StackLayout dock="top" width="100%" height="75" >
            <!-- ><Label horizontalAlignment="center" text="Graphic - Step 1 thru 3 Here" /> 
            -->
            <Image class="" src="~/images/signup/step-1-on.png" stretch="fill" />
            <Image style="margin-top: 15"  src="~/images/signup/progress.png" stretch="fill" />
        </StackLayout>
          <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" width="210" height="210" backgroundColor="lightgray">
    <Label text="Label 1" width="70" height="70" backgroundColor="red"/>
    <Label text="Label 2" width="70" height="70" backgroundColor="green"/>
    <Label text="Label 3" width="70" height="70" backgroundColor="blue"/>
    <Label text="Label 4" width="70" height="70" backgroundColor="yellow"/>
  </WrapLayout>
        <!-- end content -->
    </DockLayout>
</Page>
```

Can you help me with this layout? It appears to be easy, but not for me.

Thank You.

Comment: You can use GridLayout as I created in Playground. You can play with % height and width.

Comment: Make sure you use `columns="*, *" rows="*, *"` that will eually divide height and width for each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=1Q7RZ0).

GridLayout is the king.

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="*, *" width="230" height="230"
        backgroundColor="lightgray">
        <Label text="Label 1" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red" />
        <Label text="Label 2" row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="green" />
        <Label text="Label 3" row="1" col="0" backgroundColor="blue" />
        <Label text="Label 4" row="1" col="1" backgroundColor="yellow" />
        <Label text="Label 5" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="orange" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks. I now see how it works, sort of... lol .